# How I can take text input from console using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take input from the standard input and stored it in a variable. I have written the code something like this:

```
titles = input("Please enter Wikipedia article to process: \n")
```

While running the program wait for the input and when I copy text from `wikipedia` and try to paste it it start giving error. I do not know what exactly I need to do to make my program input the paragraphs from wikipedia and also remove the reference numbers while printing it.

Here is what I got:

```
>>> titles = input("Please enter Wikipedia article to process: \n")
Please enter Wikipedia article to process:
Villa Park is a football stadium in Aston, Birmingham, England, with a seating capacity of 42,682. It has been the home of Aston Villa Football Club since 1897. The ground is less than a mile from both Witton and Aston railway stations and has hosted sixteen England internationals at senior level, the first in 1899 and the most recent in 2005. Villa Park has hosted 55 FA Cup semi-finals, more than any other stadium.
>>>
>>> In 1897, Aston Villa moved into the Aston Lower Grounds, a sports ground in a Victorian amusement park in the former grounds of Aston Hall, a Jacobean stately home. The stadium has gone through various stages of renovation and development, resulting in the current stand configuration of the Holte End, Trinity Road Stand, North Stand and the Doug Ellis Stand. The club has initial planning permission to redevelop the North Stand, which will increase the capacity of Villa Park from 42,682 to about 50,000.
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    In 1897, Aston Villa moved into the Aston Lower Grounds, a sports ground in a Victorian amusement park in the former grounds of Aston Hall, a Jacobean stately home. The stadium has gone through various stages of renovation and development, resulting in the current stand configuration of the Holte End, Trinity Road Stand, North Stand and the Doug Ellis Stand. The club has initial planning permission to redevelop the North Stand, which will increase the capacity of Villa Park from 42,682 to about 50,000.
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> Before 1914, a cycling track ran around the perimeter of the pitch where regular cycling meetings were hosted as well as athletic events. Aside from football-related uses, the stadium has seen various concerts staged along with other sporting events including boxing matches and international rugby league and rugby union matches. In 1999, the last ever final of the UEFA Cup Winners' Cup took place at Villa Park. Villa Park also hosted the 2012 FA Community Shield, as Wembley Stadium was in use for the final of the Olympic football tournament.[3]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    Before 1914, a cycling track ran around the perimeter of the pitch where regular cycling meetings were hosted as well as athletic events. Aside from football-related uses, the stadium has seen various concerts staged along with other sporting events including boxing matches and international rugby league and rugby union matches. In 1999, the last ever final of the UEFA Cup Winners' Cup took place at Villa Park. Villa Park also hosted the 2012 FA Community Shield, as Wembley Stadium was in use for the final of the Olympic football tournament.[3]
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Kindly, help me.
Please note I am using python 3.6

Comment: put the string in double quotes

Comment: Not working my friend.

Comment: "Villa Park is a football stadium in Aston, Birmingham, England, with a seating capacity of 42,682. It has been the home of Aston Villa Football Club since 1897. The ground is less than a mile from both Witton and Aston railway stations and has hosted sixteen England internationals at senior level the first in 1899 and the most recent in 2005. Villa Park has hosted 55 FA Cup semi-finals, more than any other stadium."

Comment: copy and paste exactly

Comment: @Shiva and Moses OP is really using Python 3, the problem is that they're trying to enter multiple lines.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the first three paragraphs using your techniques: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_Park

Comment: @JafferWilson you need to put `input` in a while loop and stop when the user enters a sentinel value like 'stop'. Put each line in a list.

Comment: @AlexHall I think they are not understanding what I looking for..

Comment: They took a quick glance and confused your problem with a related and very common confusion. Basically they thought you were actually using python 2.

Comment: @AlexHall can you help to solve my problem?

Comment: Do what I suggested with `input` in a loop or drop `input` entirely and read from a file instead.

Comment: @AlexHall sound a good solution let me try it.